# Attribute and relative position in a single Xpath Query?

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to set up a single Xpath query that not only searches for nodes with a specific attribute but then the relative position of it, not it's actual position within the XML.

As an example:

```
<room>
<child gender="female">
<name>Anne</name>
</child>

<child gender="female">
<name>Mary</name>
</child>

<child gender="male">
<name>John</name>
</child>

<child gender="male">
<name>David</name>
</child>
</room>
```

And I want to specify which gender and child's relative position. So in my case I want the second male in the document.

`/room/child[@gender="male]` just gives me all the males where `/room/child[position()=2]` would result in Mary being pulled.

I've already come up with a solution by giving each one another attribute of ID based on their position and can query that with a simple AND `/room/child[@gender="male" and @ID="2"` but that would require a lot work on my end to go back into all my documents and add that second attribute instead of just being able to use single simplified Xpath if possible. I also realize I could query to get the males, then query the result's position but again I'd rather to just keep it a single query if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for : `//child[@gender='male'][2]`

Comment: Yep, that seems to be working the way that I need it to. Thanks a lot!